# JSON.stringify issue while stringifying an array

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am facing a problem while fetching the value from HTML5 localstorage. When i am setting value to the key using JSON.stringify the callback is getting removed.
I am stuck with this problem.
Below is the code snippet.

```
var topics = {};
var subscribe = function (topic, fn) 
{  
if (!topics[topic]) 
{         
topics[topic] = [];}
topics[topic].push({ callback: fn,context: this  });
window.localStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify(topics[topic]));
return this;
};
var publish = function (topic) {
var args;args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
var myArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArray'));
for (var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {var subscription = myArray[i];
        subscription.callback.apply(subscription.context, args);
    }
    return this;
```

};

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: A JavaScript function does not have a corresponding [value in JSON](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.1).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no JSON implementation for storing a function.

That is why the callback is being removed.

Comment: Possibly, but I question whether this is the appropriate route to take here. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am designing a pub sub pattern in JS...for that i am storing the published action in the localstorage and then retrieving the action for the subscribers from the localstorage

Comment: I would then suggest storing an ID of some sort instead and then call your action with the ID on load from localstorage.

Comment: k Adam so JSON.stringify doesn't have support to function calls..if i remove JSON.stringify and simply use window.localStorage.getItem('myArray') i should get callback function but in subscription.callback i am receiving an exception

Answer (score 0):

As Adam correctly explained, JSON is for representing pure data and not code logic. This is a matter of separation of concerns.

The "right" way would probably be to retrieve the data from the local storage, wrap it in your custom JavaScript object which then has already functionalities attached for operating on the data. I'm thinking about something like

```
var MyDataObj = function(){
    //constructor
    //load the data from the local storage and associate it to this object like
    this.data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArray'));
};

MyDataObj.prototype.executeAction = function(){
   //peform your operations like invoking the subscriptions
};
```

The usage would then be

```
var dataObj = new MyDataObj();
dataObj.executeAction();
```

I'm not quite sure what's the intention behind your invocation of the callback methods, in my opinion your object encapsulate what to invoke and how.

Hope it helps

Comment: my scenario is Mediator.js will have publish and subscribe methods as described in my code snippet..now 1.htm broadcast an event which other html has to capture and do the necessary action as per the business logic so that is why the callback is required...i dont know whether i am making it bit complex